# How to safely copy data from Mac to Windows, preferably over network?

Tags: network, hard-drive, backup, ntfs, hfs+

I am wondering what the most reliable method is to copy a large amount (1TB) of photos from a Mac computer (external HFS+ drive) to a Windows computer (external NTFS drive)?

I am hoping to do this over a local network. But I am wondering how to make this as reliable as possible.

I see two possible network strategies but am not sure which is a better bet:

(a) Mac shares the source drive (HFS+), Windows mounts it, Windows does the copying.

(b) Windows shares the destination drive, Mac mounts it, Mac does the copying.

Thank you for any advice!

*PS, alternatives I have already considered but am hoping to avoid:*

1. *I have in the past done HFS->NTFS by going via an intermediate exFAT copy. But there are many reasons this strategy is painful and I am not even sure it is that reliable. So I am trying to find a network strategy.*
2. *I also know that in theory Mac can mount and write to NTFS using special drivers (i.e. Paragon) but I have always had the impression this is risky in terms of the risk of corrupting the destination drive.*

Comment: What's wrong with just setting up an ftp server on one of the machines? And just letting it run?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest your option (b) above: share a folder from the Windows machine and have the Mac mount it via SMB.

macOS will connect to a Windows machine with a bit less fiddling in my experience. Enabling SMB sharing for Windows on macOS requires downgrading your security settings a bit, that's also part of the reason for suggesting (b).

I will occasionally also use [PairDrop](https://pairdrop.net/) to shuttle files between peers, and that is quick, painless and does not even require them to be on the same network. You can self-host an instance of it too (that's what I do...)

Comment: Thank you luckman212!  I may need to learn rsync but I wanted to do that anyway. Do you think it’s equally reliable either way or is (b) more reliable or stable than (a)?

Comment: I was just realizing something. How do people deal with the naming discrepancies when copying HFS+ files to NTFS? I know some chars are legal in HFS+ file names but not in NTFS? Maybe tools like PairDrop deal with this, but I am guessing not all copying tools do?